# NSDate formatter Problem its getting null while converting NSString to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios4

hi to all
I am Struggling to convert NSString to NSDate with the Help of formatter but its going to be null
Can any one help please
here is my code...

```
 NSString *dateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10/26/2010/09:56:56 PM"];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
 NSDate *localDateTime =[dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
 NSLog(@"client date is %@",localDateTime);
```

Thx in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Could be because your dateString and format does not match.

```
10/26/2010/09:56:56 PM

mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a
```

Do you see the difference? :) They actually have to match. In the format you have a space between the year and hours and in the actual date there is a slash. Month you match by 'mm' which is actually minutes and should be 'MM'. Change to:

```
10/26/2010 09:56:56 PM

MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a
```

There might be more problems so I suggest you actually look at the [guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];

NSDate *formatterDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1999-07-11 at 10:30"];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Try this out.